# Unable to set up Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been using ListView all this time and trying out Recycler view now. Been trying to follow the documentation for the basic setup but frustratingly unable to do so.

The ViewHolder class is supposed to take in a TextView parameter but in the documentation site, the example is inputting a View as a parameter and I don't get how that is supposed to work. I tried to cast it with TextView and get a ClassCastException. I have commented above the line which gives error preventing me from compiling. Error is in MyAdapter Class.

I apologize if I am just bad at reading documents, otherwise plain ridiculous for this to come from an official site. [Official page](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        String[] myDataset = {"item 1", "item 2"};

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter Class

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

        //THIS is the line causing error. v is View. I should be inputting a textview. 
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }

}
```

my textview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So put in a `TextView`. Please provide `R.layout.my_text_view` - I'm going to assume it will look like `<LinearLayout><TextView/></LinearLayout>`. Remove the wrapping layout from your textview and it should work.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak If I put in a textview, how do I pass in my View v then? Added xml

Comment: A `TextView extends View`, `View` is its super class and you can just use a `TextView` in its place. Please, provide your layout xml as mentioned.

Comment: Remove the linearlayout, add the namespace to the textview, and it should work

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Sorry I don't get it. I understand that View is the super class. But I would have to pass in that inflate. Do u mean instead of View v = LayoutInflater... go with TextView v = LayoutInflater... If not can you show me an example please. I will remove the Linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `LinearLayout` back from the inflate:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
// v <- LinearLayout
```

Now, you can either

1. Remove the wrapping LinearLayout, so that you get a `TextView` in your xml, you then would need to cast your adapter

   ```
   ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((TextView) v);
   ```
2. adapt your ViewHolder to accept a View or LinearLayout

   ```
   public ViewHolder(View v) {
     mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
   }
   ```

Comment: Going with option 2. Works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following. Or change the constructor of `ViewHolder` class to take as parameter a `View`, like this

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
}
```

and change the `onCreateViewHolder` method like this

```
   @Override
    public MemebershipAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.site_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        vh.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        return vh;
    }
```

Or you can keep your constructor, and change the `onCreateViewHolder` method like this

```
@Override
public MemebershipAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.site_item, parent, false);

    TextView mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(mTextView);

    return vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewHolder must look like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    }
}
```

don't forget to put android:id="@+id/textViewId" to your TextView in the layout